# Including a partial "as is" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using [stache](https://github.com/agoragames/stache) for server-side evaluation of [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) templates. I would like to re-use some of these templates on the client-side from JavaScript using [ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/), but to do so I need to include them into script tags. I would like to avoid duplicating the templates (DRY), but obviously, the templates must *not* be evaluated before being sent to the client, so using a simple `render :partial` invocation like in this (HAML) snippet does *not* work:

```
%script{:id => 'project_snippet'}
  = render :partial => 'project'
```

Is there any way to include a partial without evaluating it using the underlying template engine (kind of like a raw include)?

In other places the partial is to be used as regular partial, i.e., evaluation is supposed to happen, so changing the file extension to always avoid evaluation is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that I should have read the stache documentation: There is a tag helper available, so

```
= template_include_tag 'projects/project'
```

will do the trick after setting the template base directory in an initializer:

```
Stache.configure do |c|
  c.template_base_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/views"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need a partial **as is** or you want it to be rendered as HTML with some placeholders for JavaScript templating? you can pass `:locals => { ... }` with something to be replaced by JS template engine later i.e.

```
 %script{:id => 'project_snippet'}
   = render :partial => 'project', :locals => {:name => '{{{ project_name }}}'}
```

if **as is** then read the partial content (but it doesn't look like you want this)

```
 %script{:id => 'project_snippet'}
   = File.open("#{path/to}/partial.html.haml", "r").read
```

Comment: Actually, the latter is what I want as my template is already a .mustache file - no need for any substitutions. Is there an easy way to figure out the path to the template directory (left as "#{path/to}" in your example) in Rails 3.1?

Comment: take a look http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/resolver_rb.html

Comment: or `Rails.root.join("app/views/#{controller.controller_name}/partial.html.haml")` (not elegant though)